# Performance and Pros/Cons of using INNER JOIN as filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working on MS SQL Server and has been following standard SQL Query to do INNER JOIN and filter the resultset based on the criteria.

Recently, I was working with a large table where it has somehow cause the whole query to take ridiculous long time to do a query.

Below is just a mock query of the situation.

```
Select * FROM Customer a
INNER JOIN ProcessTable PT WITH(NOLOCK) on PT.custID = a.ID
INNER JOIN AuditTrailTable AT WITH(NOLOCK) on AT.custID = a.ID
WHERE AT.DATESTAMP > 'Some date time'
```

My colleague has come up with a new query as below

```
Select * FROM Customer a
INNER JOIN ProcessTable PT WITH(NOLOCK) on PT.custID = a.ID
INNER JOIN AuditTrailTable AT WITH(NOLOCK) on AT.DATESTAMP > 'Some date time' AND AT.custID = a.ID
```

in which I observed he has put the filter clause as part of the INNER JOIN.

Despite it returns the same result, I would like to know the performance gain of this approach and pros and cons that I have not aware of please. Will it be a good approach of using this?

Answer (score 1):

The two should be *exactly* the same.  SQL Server's compiler will look at the queries and realize they are describing the same result set.  It will then optimize the query plan based on the data.

Whether the condition goes in the `on` clause or the `where` clause does not matter for an `inner join`.  (It does matter for an `outer join`.)

Comment: *"Whether the condition goes in the on clause or the where clause does not matter for an inner join"* >> I know from experience that that is not always the case. At least in one case in a project I'm on, moving several conditions from the WHERE clause to the JOIN clause allowed the query optimizer for a much better execution plan. Admittedly, the query was more complex than the one from the OP. So I wouldn't generalize it in a statement like that.

Comment: @TT. . . . Here is a reference:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61220/putting-a-condition-related-to-a-table-in-join-is-better.  You may be experiencing something different.  If the join conditions are very complex on your query, then SQL Server may not consider every possible join combination.  In that case, a "random" subset of joins would be considered, and this might differ based on the ordering of the tables and join conditions.  However, whether one produces a better or worse plan would be entirely arbitrary.